# Convert a date in french format in a mysql datetime format

Tags: php, datetime, date

I'd like to convert a date in french format (08 novembre 2011 à 06h00) in a datetime format (2011-11-08 06:00).

I'm able to convert a datetime in french format date with a little function:

```
function dateFR($datetime) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR');
    return strftime('%d %B %Y &agrave; %Hh%M', strtotime($datetime));
}
```

But I don't know how to do the opposite.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I can think of a dozen ways to do this offhand - with preg_match, explode, date, foreach, etc. Be good practice for you to figure this out for yourself, it sounds like you have very little experience with programming.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Benubird and for the examples. I'm trying for myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about?

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($datetime));
```

Ah, yes, I see the problem. `strtotime` only converts english text (emphasis mine):

> The function expects to be given a string containing an **English** date format and will try to parse that format into a Unix timestamp

Your best bet is probably going to be `preg_match` for your specific format, as there doesn't seem to be any locale-specific functions that will convert things like the month name.

Comment: Thank you DTest, I've already try that but it doesn't work :(
The result is always: 1970-01-01 01:00

Comment: @beno what's the return value of strototime($datetime) ?

Comment: The result value is 1970-01-01 01:00 when I do that:

    $date_fr = "08 novembre 2011 à 06h00";
    $datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime($date_fr));
    echo "datetime: ".$datetime."<br />";

Comment: Ok, I understand, thank you.
So I'll try to first convert my specific date format in an english date format with preg_match before I use strtotime.

Comment: This cannot be an answer

Answer (score 4):

I just wrote this to convert a french date in day/months/year to english format and next to MYSQL. Assuming original date is separated by a "/" slash

```
    private function dateToMySQL($date){
        $tabDate = explode('/' , $date);
        $date  = $tabDate[2].'-'.$tabDate[1].'-'.$tabDate[0];
        $date = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date) );
        return $date;
    }
```

It's pretty basic and warn if missing numbers like day.

Answer (score 1):

if you have array or multiArray i made this function, juste all you date input start with name="date_...."

```
function dateFormatSql(&$array){
foreach ($array as $key=>&$value){
    if(!is_array($value)){
        if(preg_match("#^date_#", $key)){
            $tabDate = explode('/' , $value);
            $date  = $tabDate[2].'/'.$tabDate[1].'/'.$tabDate[0];
            $sqldate =  date('Y/m/d', strtotime($date));
            $array[$key] = $sqldate;
        }
    }else{
        dateFormatSql($value);
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I know question was long a time, but as I've just had same probleme, I propose this solution :

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i',$datetime)->format('Y-m-d H:i')
```

But PHP 5.3 required.
More information on http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 1):

try this code :

```
function frToEn($date){
/* this function Convert a date in french format to english format
** EXP : 
**  French date  : 20-juin-2019
**  English date :  20-jun-2019
*/
$month=substr($s1=substr($date,strpos($date,'-')+1) , 0 , -(strlen($s1)-strpos($s1,"-")));
$year=substr($s1,strpos($s1,'-')+1);
$day=substr($date,0,strpos($date,'-'));

switch ($month) {
    case 'janvier': 
    case 'janv': 
    case 'jan':
        return $day."-jan-".$year;
        break;
    case 'février' :
    case'févr' :
    case'fév':
        return $day."-feb-".$year;
        break;
    case 'mars' :
    case'mar':
        return $day."-mar-".$year;
        break;
    case 'avril' :
    case'avr':
        return $day."-apr-".$year;
        break;
    case 'mai':
        return $day."-may-".$year;
        break;
    case 'juin':
        return $day."-jun-".$year;
        break;
    case 'juillet' :
    case'juil':
        return $day."-jul-".$year;
        break;
    case 'aout' :
    case'août':
        return $day."-aug-".$year;
        break;
    case 'septembre' :
    case'sept' :
    case'sep':
        return $day."-sep-".$year;
        break;
    case 'octobre' :
    case'oct':
        return $day."-oct-".$year;
        break;
    case 'novembre' :
    case'nov':
        return $day."-nov-".$year;
        break;
    case 'décembre' :
    case'déc':
        return $day."-dec-".$year;
        break;

    default:
        return false;
        break;
}}
```

for the mysql format use this function :

```
date('Y-m-d',strtotime(frToEn($date))
```