# Parse french date in php

Tags: php, date

I have string:

*"Lundi, 08 Juillet 2013 09:09"*

How can I parse this type string?

I try:

```
    $date = '08 Juillet 2013 09:09';
    $date = new \DateTime($date);
```

But it throw exception

Comment: possible duplicate of [strtotime With Different Languages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988536/strtotime-with-different-languages)

Comment: does this answer gives you some light: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8051979/188331 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$date = '08 Juillet 2013 09:09';;
$find = array('janvier', 'février', 'mars', 'avril', 'mai', 'juin', 'juillet', 'août', 'septembre', 'octobre', 'novembre', 'décembre');
$replace = array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');
$date = str_replace($find, $replace, strtolower($date));
date = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($date));
```

Comment: Nice one! But you forgot "octobre" in the $find array :)

Answer (score 12):

The [`intl`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) extension can be used for this:

```
// create formatter
$fmt = new IntlDateFormatter(
    "fr-FR", 
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL, 
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL, 
    'Etc/UTC', 
    IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN, 
    'EEEE, dd MMMM y hh:mm'
);

// parse
$ts = $fmt->parse('Lundi, 08 Juillet 2013 09:09');
echo $ts; // 1373274540
```

Comment: worth noting that `intl` is only available for PHP >=5.2, but this is definitely the best solution. +1

Comment: This should become the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your format is fixed, use [`strptime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php) in combination with French [locale](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php):

```
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR');
$date = '08 Juillet 2013 09:09';
$date = strptime($date, '%d %B %Y %H:%M'); 
var_dump($date);
```

See [strftime](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.strftime.php) for description of `format` string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [**strftime**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php). If there's only one language and you use shared hosting where french isn't supported, you could build an array with the months, and replace them with the english version.

Answer (score 0):

try this code, its important to first use `setlocale`

```
 $date = '08 Juillet 2013 09:09';
 setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fr-FR');
 $time = strptime($date, "%d %B %G %H:%M");
 print_r($time);
```

Answer (score 0):

in `DateTime` standard  only support this list

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

```
DateTime::ATOM 
DATE_ATOM
Atom (example: 2005-08-15T15:52:01+00:00)
DateTime::COOKIE 
DATE_COOKIE
HTTP Cookies (example: Monday, 15-Aug-05 15:52:01 UTC)
DateTime::ISO8601 
DATE_ISO8601
ISO-8601 (example: 2005-08-15T15:52:01+0000)
DateTime::RFC822 
DATE_RFC822
RFC 822 (example: Mon, 15 Aug 05 15:52:01 +0000)
DateTime::RFC850 
DATE_RFC850
RFC 850 (example: Monday, 15-Aug-05 15:52:01 UTC)
DateTime::RFC1036 
DATE_RFC1036
RFC 1036 (example: Mon, 15 Aug 05 15:52:01 +0000)
DateTime::RFC1123 
DATE_RFC1123
RFC 1123 (example: Mon, 15 Aug 2005 15:52:01 +0000)
DateTime::RFC2822 
DATE_RFC2822
RFC 2822 (Mon, 15 Aug 2005 15:52:01 +0000)
DateTime::RFC3339 
DATE_RFC3339
Same as DATE_ATOM (since PHP 5.1.3)
DateTime::RSS 
DATE_RSS
RSS (Mon, 15 Aug 2005 15:52:01 +0000)
DateTime::W3C 
DATE_W3C
```

it must be `08 July 2013 09:09` instead of `08 Juillet 2013 09:09` or use `strtotime` instead if you can't change  `Juillet` to `July`